# Simple file upload validate request with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, validation

Validate an input field of HTML form is a simple operation, as follows:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

    public function adminPassword(Request $request) 
    {
        $this->parameters = $request->request->all();
           ...
        $new_password = $this->parameters['new_password'];
        $validator = Validation::createValidator();
        $violations = $validator->validate($new_password, [
            new Assert\Length([
                'min' => 4
            ])
        ]);
        if (0 !== count($violations)) {
            ...
        }
           ...
    }
```

Can validation request of HTML form file upload (image), can be done by Symfony in the same simple way?

```
public function logoUpload(Request $request)
{
     $file = $request->files->get('logo');
     ...
}
```

The requirement is not using Twig, or Symfony 'Form' ('createFormBuilder'), as not done above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Symfony, the result of `$request->files->get('key')` is an `UploadedFile` or `null`.

With an `UploadedFile` you can use your validator with a [file constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html) as the example below :

```php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File; 
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolationListInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;

...

public function validateFile(Request $request): ConstraintViolationListInterface
{
   $fileConstraints = new File([
       'maxSize' => '64M',
       'maxSizeMessage' => 'The file is too big',
       'mimeTypes' => ['pdf' => 'application/pdf'],
       'mimeTypesMessage' => 'The format is incorrect, only PDF allowed'
   ]);

   $validator = Validation::createValidator();
   
   return $validator->validate($request->files->get('key'), $fileConstraints);
}
```

The method returns an iterator of constraints.

**Please note to use MimeTypes you need to install symfony/mime on your app**

Comment: In '.. = new File([...])' I'm getting error 'Expected type 'string'. Found 'string[]''?

Comment: It seems we don't have the same constructor for this constraints, which version of Symfony are you using ? Can you send me the constructor signature of your 'File' constraints please ?

Comment: I use standalone Symfony components in my app. Based on 'Kernel.php' 
public const VERSION = '6.1.4';

__construct()

Comment: I changed to '..\Constraints\File; '  it was ' ../HttpFoundation\File\File;'. Also, please note $file is '..->files->get('logo')', not '..->file' (plural), now I'm getting the following error message: "You cannot guess the mime type as the Mime component is not installed. Try running "composer require symfony/mime".

Comment: After running "composer require symfony/mime" I got the validation to work, Thx.

Comment: This answer is more helpful and undestandable than the Symfony documentation is.